# QSS stylesheet applied not completly on QListWidget

Tags: qt4, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to apply styles to some of my widgets via qss file, font and font size works correctly, but QListWidget::item:selected background color gets ignored.
Here's my qss code:

```
QListWidget, QLabel {
    font: Sans Serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

QListWidget::item:selected {
    backgorund: #FE8080;
}
```

also tried it like this:

```
QListWidget {
    selection-background-color: rgb(254,128,128);
}
```

and here's how i'm connecting it

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
server w;
QFile* styles = new QFile(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/qss/default.qss");
styles->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString appliedStyles = styles->readAll();
a.setStyleSheet(appliedStyles);
```

trying to run this on windows, qt 4.8.6. Tried to use "background" and "background-color" no changes. I guess i'm doing something wrong, maybe someone can point me in the right direction and explain to me how to get this working?

Comment: Do you really have `backgorund`?

Comment: @G.M I tried different rules such as "background" and "background-color", also tried "selection-background-color" , last option worked on Ubuntu, but not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that was the source of my problem, but setting up Application style helped, all styles applied as they should.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setStyle("windowsxp");
```